# How to filter a fact table by dimensional date field when the fact table values are aggregated by year?

Tags: powerbi

I have a date dimensional table and a fact table for population per city per year that I want to be able to filter using the date in the dimensional table.

Dim table (has more fields as well):

| Date | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-31 | 2022 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023 |

Fact table:

| Year | City | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | City A | 100,000 |
| 2023 | City A | 105,000 |
| 2022 | City B | 200,000 |

etc.

I want to be able to create a measure that would do something like divide the number of transactions for a month (from another fact table) / the population for that year (calculated at a city level).

But I can't figure out how to link the year in the dimensional table with the year in the fact table without it being a many-to-many relationship.

I tried to create a dimensional table for just the "year" value and link the two tables that way, but the connection did not work between the dim - date table and the fact table when I did that.

Would the only way to do this be to build out the population table so it has values for each day and have the measure do an average/min or max for that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Date column to your Fact table that would be the first day of that year. For example:

| Date | Year | City | Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | City A | 100,000 |
| 2023-01-01 | 2023 | City A | 105,000 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022 | City B | 200,000 |

You could add this column in PowerQuery or DAX with:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Date", each #date([Year], 1, 1), type date)
```

```
Date = DATE([YEAR], 1, 1)
```

Use this new date column for the relationship to the Dim Date table.

Next you will need a Measure similar to this one to give you the Population for the year by using YTD function:

```
Population YTD = TOTALYTD( SUM('FactTable'[Population]), 'Dim Date'[Date] )
```

You can then use this measure in your other calculations.